# Ask for certification each time I login

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having issues trying to develop a login that asks me always for a digital certification. Right now the pop up only shows the first time I login, after that Chrome itself uses the previously used certificate to login. **The idea is to show the pop up each time I login**

I alredy have this

Login petition to backend

```
   const upload = await axios({
      url: "http://localhost:3006/login",
      method: "POST",
      timeout: 18000,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
```

The backend

```
https.createServer({
  agent: false,
  catCheckKeyExists: false,
  maxCachedSessions:0,
  keepAliveTimeout:0,
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  SNICallback: (servername, cb) => {
    // here you can even change up the `SecureContext`
    // based on `servername` if you want
    cb(null, ctx);
  }
}, app).listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log("HTTPS server listening on port " + PORT + "...");
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  let certificado=req.connection.getPeerCertificate(true);
  if(certificado && certificado.subject){
  let base64data = certificado.raw.toString('base64');
  let dataResult=  {}
  if(certificado?.subject?.SN && certificado?.subject?.GN){
    dataResult.nombre=certificado.subject.SN ,
    dataResult.primerApellido=certificado.subject.GN
    dataResult.numIdentificacion=certificado.subject.serialNumber
  }else{
   if(certificado.serialNumber){
        dataResult.numIdentificacion=certificado.serialNumber;
    }
   if(certificado.subject?.CN){
        dataResult.nombre=certificado.subject.CN;
       dataResult.primerApellido="";
   }
 }
   res.status(200).send({'status':'OK',data:dataResult});
}else{
res.status(200).send({'status':'OK',data:null});
}
})
```